# "The Epicures" or "The Epicureans"? Which makes more sense today?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose someone wanted to form a club, or a society, whose members would be folks tending to cultivate a refined taste in everything: food, clothes, cultural events, etc.

Would *The Epicures* or *The Epicureans* be the better name for it?

Which of the two terms has the connotations tying it down to the present, rather than ancient Greece and the actual Epicure's followers?

Comment: I would say "Epicureans" is more idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks: So would I, or at least I did until I started poking around various websites with an eye to confirming this view, as  he that increaseth knowledge increaseth frustration.

Comment: Which is more idiomatic really doesn't matter. The name is already too abstruse for most people who'll encounter it, and the fussbudgets among those who do know the difference will argue for whichever you *didn't* choose anyway.

Comment: @Robusto:  Well, ain’t that just lovely. Mind suggesting what ordinary people not given to fuss budgeting would call an epicurean? Apart from snooty pants smart ass, I mean?

Comment: Then there will be those who wonder where the picureans were before the internet

Comment: @Phil Sweet: So, where were they?

Comment: Google Books shows that Epicureans is a much more common  vs Epicures. As for which is the “better”, that’s POB issue. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Epicures%2CEpicureans&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CEpicures%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CEpicureans%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about choosing a name.